# Ruby write and read into binary file using pack and unpack

Tags: ruby, binary, pack, unpack

I'm working on the basic Ruby read/write for binary files.

Here is my code

```
afile = File.new("test.bin",'wb')

test = "abc"
a = test.unpack("B*")

File.open("test.bin", 'wb' ) do |output|
  output.write a
end

print ("write #{a}\n") #Output "write ["011000010110001001100011"]

b = a.pack("B*")
print ("b is #{b}\n") #Output "b is abc"
```

So far everything looks good. Then I tried to read from the file and turn it back to the ASCII form.

```
s = File.binread("test.bin")
bits = s.pack("B*")

print ("s is #{s}\n") #Output is "s is ["011000010110001001100011"]"
print ("bits is #{bits}\n")
```

Then there's an error.

" extract.ruby:23:in `<main>': undefined method`pack' for "[\"011000010110001001100011\"]":String (NoMethodError) "

Could anyone help me to explain this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: appears that #unpack actually returns/creates an array: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-unpack

Comment: Did you mean that I didn't create the binary file in the right way? So is there anything like "binwrite" to create the real binary file?

Comment: Thanks! I got it. I don't think I need to pack or unpack if I use binwrite and binread.

Comment: Feel free to post your code with a working solution as an "answer your own question" answer...